# Using While loop Print data till end of table

Tags: php, while-loop

```
mysql_query($query,$con);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM NW_WORLD;";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);

        $i = 0;
        $counter = count($result);
        while($result)
        {
            $village = mysql_result($result, $i, "village");
            $player = mysql_result($result, $i, "player");

            echo "village: $village  ";
            echo "player: $player<br>";
            $i++;
        }
```

I want to print all the data that I got from the Select statement. This code is working, but after the end of the table I am getting some erroneous data.

> Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 6788 on MySQL result index 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\nw_check_exec.php on line 41
>       village: player:
>       Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 6789 on MySQL result index 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\nw_check_exec.php on line 40
>       Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 6789 on MySQL result index 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\nw_check_exec.php on line 41
>       village: player:
>       Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 6790 on MySQL result index 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\nw_check_exec.php on line 40
>       Warning: mysql_result() [function.mysql-result]: Unable to jump to row 6790 on MySQL result index 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\nw_check_exec.php on line 41
>       village: player:

Please could you help me out?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun deprecation process. Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Comment: $counter = count($result); by using count on a resource you will only get the value of 1. I don't see the point of that in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried :

```
mysql_query($query,$con);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM NW_WORLD;";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $con);


        while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)**)**
        {

            echo "village: $data[village]";
            echo "player: $data[player]<br>";
        }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: I forgot a ) its the one surrounded by **)** also take them out when you put it in.

Comment: oh i know try this instead of $data['village'] use $data[village] no '
or you can use echo "player:". $data['player']."<br>";

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I only use mysql_result if I'm extracting a field from a one-column one-row (1x1) result. If you have multiple columns and/or multiple rows, I would advise you to use mysql_fetch_assoc instead.